# Aggregate JSON column

Tags: postgresql, functions, aggregate

I have a table with a JSON column in Postgres, I am grouping the rows and I am looking for some aggregate function that could "sum up" values from jsons.

sum aggregator sums the integers, I am looking for equivalent aggregator for JSONs, for example these 2 JSONs:

```
 {a: 1, b: 4}
 {b: 7, c: 3}
```

should be aggregated to

```
{a: 1, b: 11, c: 3}
```

Note that the values in conflicting keys are summed. JSONs are always 'str->int'

Is it possible to that in Postgres? Alternatively is it possible to write a custom aggregator to do that in C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first normalize the JSON data into a result that can be aggregated:

```
with data (doc) as (
  values 
    ('{"a": 1, "b": 4}'::jsonb), 
    ('{"b": 7, "c": 3}'::jsonb)
)
select k, v::int as val
from data, jsonb_each_text(doc) as t(k,v);
```

returns

```
k | v
--+--
a | 1
b | 4
b | 7
c | 3
```

This can now be aggregated per key:

```
select k, sum(v::int) s
from data, jsonb_each_text(doc) as t(k,v)
group by k;
```

returns:

```
k | s
--+----
c |  3
a |  1
b | 11
```

This can now be converted back and aggregated into a JSON:

```
select jsonb_object_agg(k,s) as doc
from (
  select k, sum(v::int) s
  from data, jsonb_each_text(doc) as t(k,v)
  group by k
) t
```

returns

```
doc                      
-------------------------
{"a": 1, "b": 11, "c": 3}
```

Comment: Thanks! This definitely works but do you know whether writing a custom aggregating function for this use case would be possible? Custom function would definitely be way faster

Comment: @PiotrDabkowski: yes, you can write a custom function for that. But as the custome function would essentially do the same thing, I doubt it would that much faster.